# automatically handling gzip http responses in Android

Tags: android, http, gzip

Reference: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/httpagent.html#d4e1261

This page says the following code will setup `HttpClient` to automatically handle gzip responses (transparent to the user of `HttpClient`):

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.addRequestInterceptor(new RequestAcceptEncoding());
httpclient.addResponseInterceptor(new ResponseContentEncoding());
```

However, I cannot find the `RequestAcceptEncoding` and `ResponseContentEncoding` classes in the Android SDK.  Are they just missing -- do I need to write these myself?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the code that I use:

```
   mHttpClient.addResponseInterceptor(new HttpResponseInterceptor() {
       public void process(final HttpResponse response,
               final HttpContext context) throws HttpException,
               IOException {
           HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
           Header encheader = entity.getContentEncoding();
           if (encheader != null) {
               HeaderElement[] codecs = encheader.getElements();
               for (int i = 0; i < codecs.length; i++) {
                   if (codecs[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                       response.setEntity(new GzipDecompressingEntity(
                               entity));
                       return;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   });
```

You might also want to look at [SyncService.java](http://www.google.com/codesearch#l9cEcZ__q88/trunk/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/service/SyncService.java&q=gzip%20package:http://iosched%5C.googlecode%5C.com) from the Google I/O app.

Comment: Exactly what I needed -- thanks also for the reference to SyncService

Comment: Please remember that if you're using an older version of the Apache HTTP Client you might not find the `GzipDecompressingEntitiy`. You can get that code here: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpcore/trunk/httpcore-contrib/src/main/java/org/apache/http/contrib/compress/GzipDecompressingEntity.java

Answer (score 0):

Android is bundled with a rather old version of the Apache HTTP Client library which doesn't have the classes you are missing.

You can bundle a newer version of the Apache HTTP Client library with your application (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577035/apache-httpclient-4-1-on-android) answer) or use [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) instead which was introduced in API level 8.

Comment: _This class was deprecated in API level 22._